# What is "level of saturation" for transistors?

Tags: transistors, ttl, saturation

This is a term I've never heard of, and it's presented on a work analysis of a ttl nor circuit. It basically says that the transistor that links the output with the ground should have a higher "saturation level" to make the transition between output high and low faster. It's actually originally on Spanish, it says "grado de saturación", but I can't find this term anywhere else. Can you guys confirm what it means? Does it have a better translation to English?

Comment: Can  you provide the quote in context? It sounds like they're just talking about providing more drive current than necessary to saturate the transistor. We sometimes talk about "hard saturation".

Comment: The full quote is "cuando la salida es de bajo nivel, Cuanto mayor sea el grado de saturación del transistor Q, menor será el retraso en la transición de nivel bajo a alto.", it translates to "when the output is on low, the greater the level (or degree) of saturation of the Q transistor, the shorter the delay in the transition from low to high level ".

Comment: The more the transistor is saturated, the slower the recovery. Schottky TTL uses a schottky diode to limit the saturation to ensure faster recovery.